# Leer y mostrar por pantalla un archivo binario completo c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para clase, en el que debo mostrar un fichero binario por pantalla justo después de almacenar algo en el mismo, el problema es que siempre me tira un error al llegar al final del archivo, y lo que me falta, es la condición del while, a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double b, a, resultat;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra el Valor de la base:");
            b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Entra el Valor de la altura:");
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            try
            {
                if (File.Exists("calculs.dat"))
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("calculs.dat", FileMode.Append)))
                    {
                        writer.Write(b);

                        writer.Write(a);

                        resultat = (0.5)*(b*a);

                        Console.WriteLine("Resultat: " + resultat);
                        writer.Write(resultat);

                        Console.WriteLine("Fitxer actualitzat correctament, polsa una tecla per continuar");
                        Console.Read();
                    }

                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("calculs.dat")))
                    {
                        Console.Clear();

                        Console.WriteLine("Fitxer de càlculs:\n----------------------------------------");


                        while (reader != ) //Aquí no se hasta qué tengo que leer
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Base: " + reader.ReadDouble());
                            Console.WriteLine("Altura: " + reader.ReadDouble());
                            Console.WriteLine("Resultat: " + reader.ReadDouble());
                            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter writerElse = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("calculs.dat", FileMode.Create)))
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine("Fitxer creat correctament");

                        writerElse.Write(b);

                        writerElse.Write(a);


                        resultat = (0.5) * (b * a);

                        Console.WriteLine("Resultat: " + resultat);
                        writerElse.Write(resultat);

                        Console.WriteLine("Polsa una tecla per continuar");
                        Console.Read();
                    }

                    using (BinaryReader readerElse = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("calculs.dat")))
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Fitxer de càlculs:\n----------------------------------------");

                        while (readerElse != ) //Aquí igual
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Base: " + readerElse.ReadDouble());
                            Console.WriteLine("Altura: " + readerElse.ReadDouble());
                            Console.WriteLine("Resultat: " + readerElse.ReadDouble());
                            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error general");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

        } //end Main
    }//end class
}//end namespace
```

> El error dice que no se puede leer más allá de la secuencia

Comment: que error?? cual while???

Comment: Son los dos whiles que hay en los readers, y el error ahora lo coloco

Comment: Error colocado!

Comment: llegaste al final del archivo... te lo dice el error...

Comment: Creo recordar que esto ya lo hablamos. Porque usas un binaryreader para esto? lo unico que haces es complicarte la vida...

Comment: Entonces que comprobación debería poner en while para que me sacara del bucle antes de que tire el error? He probado con != null, y me lo sigue tirando...

Comment: no se cual es el flag de EOF de ese reader.. el help de ese reader que dice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de la condición del `while` deberás comprobar que no estés en la última posición, para ello puedes hacerlo así:

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("calculs.dat")))
{
    while (reader.BaseStream.Position != reader.BaseStream.Length) 
    {
        //Aquí debes hacer el reader.ReadDouble(); pero tienes que tener en cuenta que solo 
        //puedes hacer uno por cada loop del reader ya que cada vez que lo haces lees 
        //8 bytes y los avanzas dentro del reader por lo que la comprobación que hacemos en
        // el while no contempla esa posibilidad, siquieres hacer 3 readDouyble en el mismo loop comprueba antes que la posicion en la que estas te permita avanzar 24bytes sin que sea el final.
        Console.WriteLine( reader.ReadDouble());

    }

}
```